# How to access and set n-dimensional list elements using a list of dimension indices

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am trying to access and set the value of elements in multidimensional lists using a list of indices for each dimension, and I am having some difficulty. Please see a simplified version of the problem I am encountering below.

While `torch`, `numpy`, and other tensor/array representations can easily be used to do this, the objects residing the multidimensional lists I am using are of different data types, so I would like to find a way to do this without the use of `numpy` or related libraries, including `torch`.

`reduce(operator.getitem, index, lst)` can be used to access elements accordingly, however, it cannot be used to set the value of elements, i.e., `reduce(operator.getitem, index, lst) = val` will raise an error.

As far as I am aware, `getattr()` and `setattr()` cannot be used to index lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import torch

tensor = torch.zeros(3, 5, 3)
tensor[2][1][0] = 1

lst = []
for i in range(3):
    lst.append([])
    for j in range(5):
        lst[i].append([])
        for k in range(3):
            lst[i][j].append([])

lst[2][1][0] = 1
index = [2, 1, 0]
tensor[[[i] for i in index]] = 2
print(tensor[2][1][0])

lst[[[i] for i in index]] = 2 # This raises an error.
print(lst[2][1][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would like a solution without eval, right? In that case it's easy using an object-like array library, such as NumPy.

Here's my functional example of getting and setting with the help of NumPy, with my own class:

```
import numpy as np

class Recursive:
    @staticmethod
    def set_item(obj, indices, new):
        if not type(obj).__module__ == 'numpy':
            raise "Not a NumPy Array"
        
        index = 0
        last = obj
        while index < len(indices) - 1:
            last = last[indices[index]]
            index += 1
        last[indices[-1]] = new
    @staticmethod
    def get_item(obj, indices):
        if not type(obj).__module__ == 'numpy':
            raise "Not a NumPy Array"
        
        index = 0
        last = obj
        while index < len(indices):
            last = last[indices[index]]
            index += 1
        return last
arr = np.eye(3,3)
Recursive.set_item(arr,[1,1],3)
print(arr)
print(Recursive.get_item(arr, [1,1]))
```

By the way, you'll need your list in numpy.ndarray type